# Problem solving Scientific Notation and Mantissa

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've been trying to solve the following question.

> Carry out the following calculations and express the answer in normalized scientific notation
>   with a four digit mantissa and exponent between $−159$ and $159$ inclusive.
>   $$(0.2460 \times 10^{85}) ÷ (0.5432 × 10^{−88})$$

I did the solution but having problem trying to figure the inclusive case.

Comment: Your "inclusive" case is the case of having an either large positive or large negative exponent. Your solution does not need such an extreme exponent.

Comment: $(0.2460\times 1085)\div (0.5432\times 10^{-88})=\frac {0.2460\times 1.085\times 10^3}{0.5432\times 10^{-88}}=\frac {.2460*1.085}{0.5432}\times 10^{3-(-88)}$.

Comment: What do you mean with "having problem trying to figure out the inclusive case"? The value of the expression is not even near the defined limits.